# open-api codegen doesn't add context path to the request-path url

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I use OAS 3.0 yaml spec to define APIs and use openapi-generator (v4.3.1) to generate controller interface and models.

Below is the spec for which the codegen works fine (notice the urls in the '**paths**' and '**servers**' keys):

```
openapi: '3.0.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: "My API"
servers:
  - url: https://my.api.com/employee
    description: Employee API
paths:
  /details/v2/address:
    get:
      // <rest of the spec> ..
```

However, I have been asked to move "/details/v2" to the **servers.url** key at the top of the spec as this part of the url is common for all the endpoints.

So now the modified spec is something like.

```
openapi: '3.0.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: "My API"
servers:
  - url: https://my.api.com/employee/details/v2
    description: Employee API
paths:
  /address:
    get:
      // <rest of the spec> ..
```

But the problem is that the newly generated interface does not contain the expected url in the RequestMapping annotation. Below is actual and expected code:

**actual generated code:** `@RequestMapping(value = "/address", produces = { "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)`

**expected code:** `@RequestMapping(value = "/details/v2/address", produces = { "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)`

I am guessing this either requires change either in the spec or in the openapi-generator config.

Please let me know what could be done to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior.  The server url doesn't go above the method.  Even if it did, it wouldn't look as you are expecting. Instead, it would have the full server address, like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "https://my.api.com/employee/details/v2/address", produces = { "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

When I used your example with [`openapi-generator V4.3.1`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/releases/tag/v4.3.1) to generate code, I got two classes.  One interface called `DefaultApi` and one Controller, which implements `DefaultApi` called `DefaultApiController`.  The `DefaultApi` interface looked like this

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/address",
    produces = { "application/json" }, 
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
default ResponseEntity<Response> stackOverflowAnswer() {
    return getDelegate().stackOverflowAnswer();
}
```

Notice the value in the `RequestMapping` is `/address`.

The key here is the api implementation, which sets the `RequestMapping` at the class level.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("${openapi.stackOverflowAnswer.base-path:/employee/details/v2}")
public class DefaultApiController implements DefaultApi {
```

Notice here how the RequestMapping has a value appended to it.  This value is expected to be set by you in your application.properties or Spring Configuration file.

However, I don't recommend that.  You should make your own controller, which implements the `DefaultApi`.  This is where you would implement your controller with your logic for how that controller (and API) should handle any requests and responses.